# Unity: player walks into trigger and animation plays once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

how do I make it that "Player walks into a trigger and an animation plays once and if the player walks into the same trigger nothing will happen" There are no videos on youtube nor other websites that I know that will explain how to do this.
Im also New to unity and am not the best when doing animations

[EDITED SCRIPT, FIXED ERRORS]

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    // You should make the name TheSecretWallScript
    // This is the general format for classes in C#
    public class Thesecretwallscript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // needed to change this.
        [SerializeField] private Animator anim;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            // Disables trigger so it doesn't trigger again
            other.enabled = false;
            // Triggers animation, "AnimTrigger" should refer to the trigger you set
            // in your animators settings
            Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
            anim.SetTrigger("AnimTrigger");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trigger for your animation in the player's Animation Controller.

You could disable the trigger once you walk into it by doing:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // Disables trigger so it doesn't trigger again
    other.enabled = false;
    // Triggers animation, "AnimTrigger" should refer to the trigger you set
    // in your animators settings
    Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    anim.SetTrigger("AnimTrigger");
}
```

Comment: Im not so familar with adding animations to object than making the triggers is there a video that you can sow me or website?

Comment: @cyberblade https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JS4k_lwmZHk that video is a pretty good, the only difference is he used a boolean in stead of a trigger, which should work similarly for your situation.

Comment: so I should make the parameter a trigger in stead of bool?

Comment: yep you could do it that way

Comment: so I wrote the scripts but I was wondering How do I add my script on stack overflow so i can show you

Comment: @cyberblade you could just edit your original question and add it in there.

Comment: As the code on top of my questions says. is the code right?

Comment: @cyberblade I edited the code to fix some errors, you should test it in unity now. If it works remember to mark an answer and close the question.

Comment: Thank you!  but I got this error (Assets\secretwallanimations\TheSecretWallScript.cs(8,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SerializedField' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)) what should i do?

Comment: @cyberblade just rename the script in unity to match the updated class name.

Comment: @cyberblade also it should be [SerializeField] when you make your Animator variable at the top

Comment: Its still not working it still says  error CS0246 unless im messing somthing up

Comment: @cyberblade did you change [SerializeField] yet?

Comment: Yes I did change it but it gave my character controller an error(([20:30:52]) Character.controller.Move called on inactive controller UnityEngine.CharacterController:Move (UnityEngine.Vector3))

Comment: @cyberblade There is no reference to a CharacterController object in that code I gave you, so the error is elsewhere unfortunately, I would recommend putting up another question related to that.

Comment: oh okay I need to add this code to my trigger right? because when I added it to my trigger nothing worked it just played the animation - last qeustion!